# Why the equality of spectral zeta functions imply the isospectrality?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, trace, zeta-functions, laplacian

Let $\Delta_{M_1}$ and $\Delta_{M_2}$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operators on two compact and connected Riemannian manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively.
We define the spectral zeta function (or Minakshisundaram–Pleijel zeta function) by:
$$
\zeta_M(s)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i^{-s},\quad Re(s)\gg 0
$$
where {$0<\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le\lambda_3\le\cdot\cdot\cdot$} are the non-zero eigenvalues of $\Delta_M$.

How can one prove the following?

> If $\zeta_{M_1}(s)=\zeta_{M_2}(s)$, then $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isospectral in the sense that the eigenvalues of $\Delta_{M_1}$ and $\Delta_{M_2}$ are identical.

Comment: Presumably the spectrum can be reconstructed from the zeta function.

Comment: For the seek of completeness it is known that Laplacian is an operator of trace class.

Comment: Assume that $\lambda_k(M_1)=\lambda_k(M_2)$ for every $k\lt i$ and that $\lambda_i(M_1)\lt\lambda_i(M_2)$ then $\lambda_i(M_1)^{-s}\gg\lambda_i(M_2)^{-s}$ when $\Re(s)\to+\infty$ hence $\zeta_{M_1}(s)-\zeta_{M_2}(s)\sim n\lambda_i(M_1)^{-s}\ne0$ for some positive integer $n$ when $\Re(s)\to+\infty$, in particular, $\zeta_{M_1}\ne\zeta_{M_2}$.

Comment: Would you be using petty edits to your post to bump it to the front page, by any chance?